# Callback of Matlab Timer

Tags: matlab, timer, preemption

The program below contains a `timer` object definition followed by its start command. Then the program continues executing other statements.

My question is whether `TimerFcn` will be called exactly after `0.01` sec, or will it wait until the for-loop completes for the timer callback function to fire?

```
% My timer object  
t = timer('TimerFcn',@(x,y)G2(z), 'StartDelay',0.01);
start(t);

% Other program statements 
for i=1:m
    ...
end
```

Comment: I'm going to refer you to [this question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10394-timer-and-interruptible-off-button-callback-priority-preemption) on MATLAB Answers. Also there was a question the other day here on SO which I think is related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24368424/97160

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line is that MATLAB is effectively single-threaded. So if a long operation is currently executing, the timer callback will not get a chance to run, and according to the timer object properties (read about [`BusyMode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/handling-timer-queuing-conflicts.html)), will instead add the event to a queue which MATLAB will eventually go through when it first gets a chance..

From what I understand (this is my own speculation), MATLAB [timers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) can interrupt execution *in between* statements, but NOT *during* a lengthy one.

So in theory it should run after 0.01 second, but there are no guarantees...

---

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-a-matlab-timer-object.html) says the following:

> Note: The specified execution time and the actual execution of a timer
>   can vary because timer objects work in the MATLAB single-threaded
>   execution environment. The length of this time lag is dependent on
>   what other processing MATLAB is performing. To force the execution of
>   the callback functions in the event queue, include a call to the
>   drawnow function in your code. The drawnow function flushes the event
>   queue.

There is also this note on another [doc page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/timer-callback-functions.html):

> Note: Callback function execution might be delayed if the callback involves a CPU-intensive task such as updating a figure.